# limit page numbers in pagination using vue js and fractal

Tags: vuejs2

Am doing pagination using vue js and fractal, from the json results am getting more than 500 pages,
how do i show 5 pages at a time rather than showing all the 500 pages at the same time.

My code looks like below, which is showing all the pages instead of breaking them in batches.

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-split">
<li class="paginate_button" v-bind:class="{'disabled': !pagination.links.previous }">
    <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous" @click.prevent="switchPage(pagination.current_page - 1)">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="paginate_button" v-for="page in pagination.total_pages" v-bind:class="{'active':pagination.current_page === page }">
    <a class="page-link" href="#" @click.prevent="switchPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
</li>

<li class="paginate_button" v-if="pagination.links.next" v-bind:class="{'disabled': !pagination.links.next }">
    <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next" @click.prevent="switchPage(pagination.current_page + 1)">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</li>
```